# Repaint with java2D and swing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

This is my first question here, so I hope it will meet the requirements.

I have developed an UI in Swing that updates its central part when the user click on radio buttons to change the number of players.
The central UI is a JPanel on which I draw (with java2D) some panels, and on each panel I display 2 labels with informations and I draw a circle for each panel.
When the UI is first displayed everything is fine, I see the circles with data for each of them. When I want to change the number of players, say from 2 to 6, I have 6 circles drawn (fine), but there is no data displayed. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong ?
To help, here are the classes concerned with a test class. The code compiles and runs.

TablePanel.java:

```
package table;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class TablePanel extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7554443317793549599L;
    private static final double X_GAP = 20.0;
    private static final double Y_GAP = 20.0;
    private static final int X_IGAP = 20;
    private static final int Y_IGAP = 20;
    private Map<String, Double> stacks;
    private int nbPlayers;

    private static final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, int[]>> coordinates = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, int[]>>();
    private static final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> layouts = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
    private static List<JPanel> players = new ArrayList<JPanel>();

    static {

        // 6
        Map<Integer, int[]> positions = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
        int[] x = new int[2];
        List<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();

        x[0] = 160 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 30 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(0, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 295 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 70 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(1, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 235 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 110 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(2, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 160 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 110 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(3, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 85 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 110 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(4, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 30 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 70 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(5, x);
        coordinates.put(6, positions);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 3);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 3, 4);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 4, 5);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        // 10
        positions = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 160 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 30 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(0, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 220 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 30 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(1, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 285 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 45 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(2, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 285 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 100 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(3, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 220 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 110 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(4, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 160 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 110 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(5, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 100 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 110 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(6, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 45 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 100 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(7, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 45 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 45 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(8, x);
        x = new int[2];
        x[0] = 100 + X_IGAP;
        x[1] = 30 + Y_IGAP;
        positions.put(9, x);
        coordinates.put(10, positions);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);

        index = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        layouts.put(index.size(), index);
    }

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public TablePanel(Map<String, Double> stacks) {
        this.stacks = stacks;
        this.nbPlayers = stacks.size();
        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 1024));
    }

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     * 
     */
    public TablePanel(int nbPlayers) {
        this.nbPlayers = nbPlayers;
        init(nbPlayers);
        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 1024));
    }

    private void init(int nbPlayers) {
            stacks = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++) {
                    String s = "A" + String.valueOf(i);
                    stacks.put(s, 0.0);
            }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawTable(g2);
                drawPlayers(g2);
    }

    private void drawPlayers(Graphics2D g2) {
        System.out.println("painting players...");
        Map<Integer, int[]> positions = null;
        PlayerPanel player = null;

        if ((nbPlayers < 7) && (nbPlayers > 1)) {
            positions = coordinates.get(6);
        }
        if ((nbPlayers < 11) && (nbPlayers > 6)) {
            positions = coordinates.get(10);
        }

        Iterator<JPanel> itPanel = players.iterator();
        JPanel current = null;
        while (itPanel.hasNext()) {
            current = itPanel.next();
            remove(current);
        }
        players.clear();

        List<Integer> indexes = layouts.get(nbPlayers);
        Iterator<Integer> it = indexes.iterator();

        for (String position : stacks.keySet()) {
                    player = new PlayerPanel(position);
                    int i = it.next();
                    player.setBounds(positions.get(i)[0] - PlayerPanel.WIDTH,
                                    positions.get(i)[1] - PlayerPanel.HEIGHT,
                                    2 * PlayerPanel.WIDTH, 2 * PlayerPanel.HEIGHT);
                    add(player);
                    players.add(player);
        }
    }

    private void drawTable(Graphics2D g2) {
        System.out.println("painting table...");
        g2.setPaint(Color.green);
        // g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        // Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(6, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
        // BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL);
        // g2.setStroke(stroke);
        Line2D lineUp = new Line2D.Double(X_GAP + 60.0, Y_GAP + 0.0,
                X_GAP + 260.0, Y_GAP + 0.0);
        g2.draw(lineUp);
        Line2D lineDown = new Line2D.Double(X_GAP + 60.0, Y_GAP + 140.0,
                X_GAP + 260.0, Y_GAP + 140.0);
        g2.draw(lineDown);

        Arc2D leftCircle = new Arc2D.Double(X_GAP + 0.0, Y_GAP + 0.0, 140.0,
                140.0, 90.0, 180.0, Arc2D.OPEN);
        g2.fill(leftCircle);

        Arc2D rightCircle = new Arc2D.Double(X_GAP + 190.0, Y_GAP + 0.0, 140.0,
                140.0, 90.0, -180.0, Arc2D.OPEN);
        g2.fill(rightCircle);

        int x[] = new int[] { X_IGAP + 60, X_IGAP + 260, X_IGAP + 260,
                X_IGAP + 60 };
        int y[] = new int[] { Y_IGAP + 0, Y_IGAP + 0, Y_IGAP + 140,
                Y_IGAP + 140 };
        g2.fillPolygon(x, y, 4);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        Object o = evt.getNewValue();
        if (o instanceof Integer) {
            nbPlayers = (int) o;
            System.out.println("changing the number of players to: "
                    + nbPlayers);
            init(nbPlayers);
        } else {
            stacks = (Map<String, Double>) o;
            this.nbPlayers = stacks.size();
        }
        System.out.println("start to repaint...");
        repaint();
    }

    private class PlayerPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2519725144140029715L;
        private JLabel labelPosition;
        private JLabel labelStack;
        private static final int WIDTH = 20;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 20;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            drawPlayer(g2);
        }

        private void drawPlayer(Graphics2D g2) {
            System.out.println("starting to draw player panel");
            g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
            Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(1, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                    BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL);
            g2.setStroke(stroke);
            Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0.0, 0.0, (double) 2
                    * WIDTH, (double) 2 * HEIGHT);
            g2.draw(circle);
            GradientPaint cyantowhite = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.cyan, 40,
                    40, Color.white);
            g2.setPaint(cyantowhite);
            g2.fill(circle);
        }

        public PlayerPanel(String position) {
            System.out.println("In player panel constructor with position "
                    + position);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
            setBackground(Color.green);
            labelPosition = new JLabel(position);
            labelPosition.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 9));
            labelPosition.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            double value = stacks.get(position);
            if (value != 0) {
                labelStack = new JLabel(String.valueOf(value));
            } else {
                labelStack = new JLabel();
            }
            labelStack.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            labelStack.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 9));
            add(labelPosition);
            add(labelStack);
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(2 * WIDTH, 2 * HEIGHT));
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(2 * WIDTH, 2 * HEIGHT));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2 * WIDTH, 2 * HEIGHT));
        }
    }
}
```

GameDefinitionPanel.java:

```
package table;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class GameDefinitionPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3972791004390766168L;
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroupTable = new ButtonGroup();
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroupTree = new ButtonGroup();
    private int nbPlayers = 2;
    private TablePanel tablePanel;
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     * 
     * @throws TablePositionException
     */
    public GameDefinitionPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel optionsPanel = new JPanel();
        add(optionsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        optionsPanel
                .setLayout(new BoxLayout(optionsPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JLabel labelTableSize = new JLabel("Table size:");
        optionsPanel.add(labelTableSize);

        JRadioButton rdbtnHeadsUp = new JRadioButton("Heads up");
        rdbtnHeadsUp.setActionCommand("2");
        rdbtnHeadsUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sizeUpdate(e);
            }
        });
        rdbtnHeadsUp.setSelected(true);
        buttonGroupTable.add(rdbtnHeadsUp);
        optionsPanel.add(rdbtnHeadsUp);

        JRadioButton rdbtnSixHanded = new JRadioButton("Six handed");
        rdbtnSixHanded.setActionCommand("6");
        rdbtnSixHanded.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sizeUpdate(e);
            }
        });
        buttonGroupTable.add(rdbtnSixHanded);
        optionsPanel.add(rdbtnSixHanded);

        JRadioButton rdbtnFullRing = new JRadioButton("Full ring");
        rdbtnFullRing.setActionCommand("10");
        rdbtnFullRing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sizeUpdate(e);
            }
        });
        buttonGroupTable.add(rdbtnFullRing);
        optionsPanel.add(rdbtnFullRing);

        Component box = Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10));

        optionsPanel.add(box);

        JLabel labelTree = new JLabel("Start Tree:");
        optionsPanel.add(labelTree);

        JRadioButton rdbtnPreflop = new JRadioButton("Preflop");
        rdbtnPreflop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        rdbtnPreflop.setSelected(true);
        buttonGroupTree.add(rdbtnPreflop);
        optionsPanel.add(rdbtnPreflop);

        JRadioButton rdbtnFlop = new JRadioButton("Flop");
        rdbtnFlop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        buttonGroupTree.add(rdbtnFlop);
        optionsPanel.add(rdbtnFlop);

        JRadioButton rdbtnTurn = new JRadioButton("Turn");
        rdbtnTurn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        buttonGroupTree.add(rdbtnTurn);
        optionsPanel.add(rdbtnTurn);

        JRadioButton rdbtnRiver = new JRadioButton("River");
        rdbtnRiver.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        buttonGroupTree.add(rdbtnRiver);
        optionsPanel.add(rdbtnRiver);

        tablePanel = new TablePanel(nbPlayers);
        add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        addPropertyChangeListener(tablePanel);

        JPanel blindsStacksPanel = new JPanel();
        add(blindsStacksPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        blindsStacksPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(blindsStacksPanel,
                BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        JButton blindsButton = new JButton("Blinds");
        blindsStacksPanel.add(blindsButton);

        JButton btnStacks = new JButton("Stacks");
        blindsStacksPanel.add(btnStacks);

        JButton btnTournamentData = new JButton("Tournament Data");
        blindsStacksPanel.add(btnTournamentData);

        JButton OKButton = new JButton("OK");
        blindsStacksPanel.add(OKButton);

        JPanel gameTypePanel = new JPanel();
        add(gameTypePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        gameTypePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(gameTypePanel,
                BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        JComboBox gameTypeComboBox = new JComboBox();
        gameTypePanel.add(gameTypeComboBox);
    }

    private void sizeUpdate(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        int oldValue = nbPlayers;
        nbPlayers = Integer.parseInt(s);
        pcs.firePropertyChange("nbPlayers", oldValue, nbPlayers);
        repaint();
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

GameDefinitionPanelTest.java:

```
package table;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GameDefinitionPanelTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GameDefinitionPanelTest test = new GameDefinitionPanelTest();
                GameDefinitionPanel gamePanel;
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                            .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    gamePanel = new GameDefinitionPanel();
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
                    frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
                    frame.setSize(800, 600);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException
                        | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Nice code dump. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should have an idea of where the problem is. If not, then it will be hard for _us_ (strangers to your program) to figure it out (with this amount of code to sift through) The point of an MCVE is to narrow your code down into a runnable program (we can copy,paste,compile run - preferably all in one class), where only the main points of what is causing the problem is shown in code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As @peeskillet just pointed out, you should attempt to make your questions as short as possible. It will make your experience here much much better. Even shortening the code to where your debugger shows the issue will make questions easier!

Comment: The code I've posted here runs, you juste have to copy and paste it into an appropriate folder and it will run. For the second point I think (but I'm not sure) that the problem is in the method PlayerPanel(String position) that does not shwo the lables correctly although the PlayerPanel is repainted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have the courage to go through all your code, but if you're adding new JLabels (or any other JThings) to a jContainer, you need to call `revalidate()` to have them show up.